io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [enabled] of class:.DatahubHttpClient
I have an issue when i run micronaut test. i got stuck with this kind of error:

io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [enabled] of class: com.eulerhermes.jade.docless.client.datahub.DatahubHttpClient
Message: No bean of type [boolean] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).

I try to build my micronaut project and launch successfully the unit test.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
